# Не переведено сообщение тултипа при наведении на звёздочку

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/514254/199934) обнаружил, что моему вопросу выставлена какая-то звёздочка (насколько понял [отсюда](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53580), это означает, что кто-то добавил его в закладки).

У звёздочки не переведено значение атрибута `title`.

[image: Не переведённый тултип звёздочки]

Comment: "tooltip" пришлось лезть в словарь за переводом "строка-подсказка".